# How many factors are needed to obtain a product of 50000?

Tags: infinite-product

$\frac{3}{2}*\frac{4}{3}*\frac{5}{4}...=50,000$

How many factors are needed? I would appreciate an explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Look at the first few products. What cancels? Can you express the product of the first $n$ terms nicely in terms of $n$?

Comment: So it would be (n+2)/2 = 50000. Then n = 99,998. Thanks!

Comment: @NickSolonko Yep. You're welcome!